# C# nvtx nvidia nsight performance analysis

Tags: c#, cuda

Is it possible to use the NVIDIA tools extension library, nvtx, from C#?

So far I have tried the following:

```
    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\bin\x64\nvToolsExt64_1.dll", 
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
    public static extern void nvtxRangePushA(string message);

    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\bin\x64\nvToolsExt64_1.dll",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void nvtxRangePop();
```

In my .cs files I  have the following:

```
nvtxRangePushA("hi");

//some work

nvtxRangePop();
```

Doing so I get an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in myProgram.exe
```

Comment: What exact type is the `string` param in the `nvtxRangePushA` function?  You probably need to marshal the string correctly, [here is an MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22e4dash.aspx) for more reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception that you're seeing most likely due to different platforms of your code and NVTX (x86 vs x64). Make sure that your application is compiled using x64 platform.

Comment: This solved the error in the post, I have another error now, which I will return to later.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you might be interested in looking to another instrumentation option, Concurrency Visualizer Markers in Visual Studio 2012 and later. If your development environment is VS, that it's worth looking at: [how to use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755853(v=vs.110).aspx) and [API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.concurrencyvisualizer.instrumentation.markers(v=vs.110).aspx).